# Semaphore based synchronization for opencv based image processing

Tags: multithreading, boost, opencv, synchronization, semaphore

I am trying to use semaphores to synchronize two threads of OpenCV image processes. One thread keeps capturing frames from the webcam and pushes it into a circular buffer and the other stream pulls an image from the buffer and processes them. I am deleting the frame that I use after I process them.

I am using boost circular buffer libraries to implement the buffer.

Please find the exact code snippet below. I have eliminated most part of the initialization and highlighting thats necessary. The problem that I am facing is that I am able to stream and capture my webcam's frames. But the window just freezes after sometimes. On some occasions, the captured frames are not displayed correctly. May I know where am I going wrong?

```
    sem_t semaphore;

  using namespace cvb;

  using namespace std;



  CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );

    IplImage* img0;

    IplImage* img1;

    sem_t semaphore;

   boost::circular_buffer<IplImage*> cb1(200);

   int ret = sem_init(&semaphore, 1, 10); //Initializing the semaphore


void* Capture(void* arg){    



       while(1) {           
                     sem_wait(&semaphore);

             img0 = cvQueryFrame( capture );        

             cb1.push_back(img0);

            cvShowImage( "mywindow", img0 );

            sem_post(&semaphore);


        if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;

                } 



}

    void* ImageProcessing(void* arg) {      

                    while(1) {                          


            if(!cb1.empty()) {
                                   sem_wait(&semaphore);
                               img2 =  cvShowImage("result",img2);                      

                                   cb1.pop_front();          
                            sem_post(&semaphore);
                                }


                        if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;

                        }   
                                cvReleaseCapture( &capture );

                                cvReleaseImage( &img2 );

                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Capture` and `ImageProcessing` are being run in different threads, aren't they? I once tried to update HighGui windows from different threads, but it didn't work.

This is actually a problem with most if not all windowing systems: you can't make calls from different threads to update a window.

Try putting both `cvShowImage` calls in the same thread. Calls to `cvWaitKey` probably have to be made from within the same thread too.

It may be the case that `cvShowImage` must be called in the same thread in which you initialize the windows using `cvNamedWindow`. I'm not sure about this, though.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion helped! The window isn't freezing any more. I am going to blog about it